# How to fill WebBrowser TextBox's?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to log on to this [site](https://eccprd.isupplier.honeywell.com/OA_HTML/AppsLocalLogin.jsp) with my company's user and password from a winforms application, I am displaying the page on a webBrowser control, any Ideas?

Comment: I'm confused, this is a jsp page but your question is tagged with C#?

Comment: I want to log on to this site with my companys user and password from a winforms application

Comment: I can't remember what they are of the top of my head (possibly the field names) but the oracle login page will pre-populate the fields if you append the name/values in a querystring to the url.

Comment: I did try this `https://eccprd.isupplier.honeywell.com/OA_HTML/AppsLocalLogin.jsp?username=Test01` and it appeared to work FYI

Comment: @quintin: it works for username but doesn't for password

Comment: Yeah I don't think it will work as a solution for you overall anyway because it won't automatically log you in.  However through the web browser control you do have access and control over all the elements in the DOM and can directly manipulate and postback using I think the basics of the control but you might possibly need the MSHTML interfaces. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341(VS.71).aspx has some of the basics for interacting with the control via MSHTML

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need write code to find controls by tag or id like

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textName").SetAttribute("value") = "ddddd" ;
```

Before this code just make sure document is completely loaded. You can use WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler to do a check for this.

Comment: did not think the solution was this simple

Comment: do you know how to perform a click over an element?

Answer (score 4):

Minor correction to the current answer

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00$cphMainPageBody$txtDUNS").SetAttribute("value" ,"123456");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a web-UI testing framework called [watin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WatiN.aspx). But this does many things other than what you are looking for & I don't know, if you really need such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

to perform a click over an element:
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("clientlogin").InvokeMember("click");

Answer (score 0):

Install Firebug in Firefox, and open the firebug console to view the postback that is sent when you login.  You can then use this information to perform a postback using WebRequest class to login directly from your Winform application.